# Efficient way to replace strings in java

Tags: java, string

I have a string template like this:

```
http://server/{x}/{y}/{z}/{t}/{a}.json
```

And I have the values:

```
int x=1,y=2,z=3,t=4,a=5;
```

I want to know which is the efficent way to replace the `{x}` to the value of `x`, and so does `y,z,t,z`?

Comment: Do you know the exact order of the parameters in advanced, or the template could also be something like `http://server/{z}/{x}/{y}.json`?

Comment: The order is not sure, since the url may be something like this `http://server/{y}.json?x={x}&y={y}`

Comment: I read all the fllowing answsers, and it seems that all of them will require the order of the placeholders?

Comment: That's right. I think there's no built in way in Java to do it, and you should manually iterate over the string and replace the '{?}' with the accurate value.

Comment: @hguser No. You can use `http://server/{1}.json?x={0}&y={1}`.

Comment: @hguser: That information is very important, and it should have been in your question. You would have gotten better answers, as there definitely are ways to do what you are looking for. As you know, we can only answer what is being asked for...

Comment: @jlordo: That's right. I do not considered that. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do it (`C# way ;)`):

```
MessageFormat mFormat = new MessageFormat("http://server/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}.json");
Object[] params = {x, y, z, t, a};
System.out.println(mFormat.format(params));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
http://server/1/2/3/4/5.json
```

Comment: While `int x=27315`, then the formatted string is something like `.../27,315/......`. What is the problem?

Comment: You could use `Object[] params = {Integer.toString(x)};` or `Object[] params = {"" + x};`.

Answer (score 16):

```
String template = "http://server/%s/%s/%s/%s/%s.json";
String output = String.format(template, x, y, z, t, a);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `MessageFormat.java`

```
MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat("http://server/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}.json");
Object[] args = {x,y,z,t,a};
String result = messageFormat.format(args);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
http://server/{x}/{y}/{z}/{t}/{a}.json
```

If you can change that to `http://server/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}.json` you can use `MessageFormat`:

```
String s = MessageFormat.format("http://server/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}/{4}.json", x, y, z, t, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace the placeholders exact how you use them in example, you can use `StrinUtils.replaceEach`

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.replaceEach(
"http://server/{x}/{y}/{z}/{t}/{a}.json",
new String[]{"{x}","{y}","{z}","{t}","{a}"},
new String[]{"1","2","3","4","5"});
```

However, `MessageFormat` will be more efficient, but requiring to replace x with 0, y with 1 etc.

If you change your format to

```
"http://server/${x}/${y}/${z}/${t}/${a}.json",
```

you can consider using [Velocity](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2001/jw-1228-velocity.html), which has parser specialized on finding ${ and } occurences.

The most efficient way would be to write own parser searching for next { occurence, than }, than replacing the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

This Could be probable answer.

```
    String url= "http://server/{x}/{y}/{z}/{t}/{a}.json";
    int x=1,y=2,z=3,t=4,a=5;

    url = url.replaceAll("\\{x\\}", String.valueOf(x));
    url = url.replaceAll("\\{y\\}", String.valueOf(y));
    url = url.replaceAll("\\{z\\}", String.valueOf(z));
    url = url.replaceAll("\\{t\\}", String.valueOf(t));
    url = url.replaceAll("\\{a\\}", String.valueOf(a));

    System.out.println("url after : "+ url);
```